# Play framework unload jars at runtime

Tags: jvm, playframework-2.0, classloader

I am trying to manage my dependencies of my play framework application. I am trying to remove/update some jar that exists in my classpath. Does that even possible?

It would be great to get an explanation of how does play framework manages classloaders. I understood that in order to obtain hot redeployment of code in development mode Play is restarting the application classloader and loads all classes again. Does it right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It's not really Play managing the hot reloading but rather the Play SBT plugin.

A Play application's `main` method is in `play.core.server.NettyServer`. The method receives a reloader of type `SBTLink` and each time a request hits the server, the application delegates the task of checking if there have been any code changes to the reloader.

If there has been a code change then the existing classloader is removed and replaced with a new one which includes the updated bytecode. The application is restarted but, of course, the JVM is not.

Play is not designed to provision dynamic swapping of Jars at runtime. For this, you would need to look at things like OSGi (which I would not personally recommend after a few years of working with it).

Comment: Why don't you recommend on osgi? It seems to answer on my needs, but I don't really see how it integrates with my Play framework application? It would be great to have some guidance,  thanks a lot!

Comment: The pros and cons of OSGi is quite a lengthy debate. Lets just say that from a personal perspective I dont like it for building Online applications. For service-based architectures where plugins are a core feature ie. tools like IDEs it is a good choice but in practise I have found that it is often not worth the while investing the time in OSGi for web applications. You cannot practically integrate Play with OSGi - they are designed for relatively different use cases. OSGi will likely solve your runtime requirements but then how important is it to your project?

Comment: Well it is not a must have requirement for my project, but it is a feature that would help us in many cases. How would you implement it with Play application? Or is it forcing me to change my framework? I found vert.x that seem to answer my needs, do you have an opinion about it? Thanks.

Comment: I think you will struggle to achieve this with Play because it is not designed for modularity in the sense in which you are talking - it is a meant to be a rapid development platform. If you want rapid results and have a small team then drop your modularity requirements - if you have a biggish project with multiple teams wanting to deploy different versions of packages without having to couple all their releases then you could think OSGi.